# Adding mouseover popups to d3 tree leaves

Tags: javascript, tree, d3.js

I have come across this nice example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/1249394) of building a collapsible animated indented tree
using d3.

How can I add a popup that works when a `mouseover` event occurs on the leaf nodes?
The popup should appear next to the actual node.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When using tags select most popular ones (langage/technology etc.) This will help people to find it and answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can do almost anything you want on mouseover and mouseout by adding .on events to the nodeEnter.append("svg:circle") section:

```
nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
  //.attr("class", "node")
  //.attr("cx", function(d) { return source.x0; })
  //.attr("cy", function(d) { return source.y0; })
  .attr("r", 4.5)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; })
  .on("mouseover", addLabel)
  .on("mouseout", clearLabel)
  .on("click", click);
```

Along with these two lines, you will have to write addLabel and clearLabel functions (like the click function that shows or hides the child nodes in the example).

You could have the popup appear by the node by passing its position to the function or by positioning it relative to the mouse.